# I am getting 500 server error while using database notification in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**this is my error**

[image: Postman Error message]

**this is my code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable; 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue; 
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage; 
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class VehicleRequestNotification extends Notification {
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    protected $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->data
        ];
    } }
```

Comment: did you run composer install?

Comment: yes I have tried :composer install,  composer update and composer dump-autoload

Comment: I guess your problem in someother code